# Android elements overlapping when dynamically inserting fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

My project consists of a main activity which loads different fragments into view when tabs are pressed on the bottom navigation bar. Blue depicts the activity controls, orange what should be included from one of the fragments. In this case, it is a MapBox `MapView` with FABs in the corners.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the fragment container height correct; either the top or bottom button (sometimes both) is always cut off vertically underneath the status bar or bottom navigation bar.

[image: Crappy PowerPoint mockup depicting a mobile screen with a status bar, embedded fragment, bottom navigation bar, and floating action buttons in each of the right-hand corners]

My current layout (irrelevant attributes removed for brevity):

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_bottom">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_bottom">
    </BottomNavigationView>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_map.xml:**

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    </MapView>

    <FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map_view"
        mapbox:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/map_view" />

    <FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/map_view"
        mapbox:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/map_view" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

I am adding the fragment to the activity like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "myFrag")
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout style **activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    orientation = vertical>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        weight = "1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_bottom">

    </BottomNavigationView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and your **fragment_map.xml:**

```
<RelaytiveLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </MapView>

    <FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        alignParentRight = true />

    <FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        alignParentRight = true
        alignParentBottom = true />

</RelaytiveLayout>
```

edited your fragment_map.xml see the changes

Comment: It appears to work with just the changes to `activity_main` which would make sense since ConstraintLayout is just a new RelativeLayout. Why does  changing the weight and height fix the problem though?

Comment: Your Problem is solved or not ? And usually ConstraintLayout should use when you have complex layout or you have multiple nested child. But if you have simple layout, should use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: You should use Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to properly format your source code chunks.

Comment: Thanks for guideline.